# Matching on the result of File::create

Tags: error-handling, rust

I am trying to write a library which must open files and I want to handle the `Result` type used by `std::fs::File::create`. I cannot figure out how to match on the return result given this wrapper function:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;

pub fn allocate(path:& str) -> File{
  let mut file = File::create(Path::new(path));
}
```

which is then invoked:

```
mod whisper;
use std::io::Write;

fn main(){
  let mut handle = whisper::allocate("./a_file.wsp");

  match handle {
    Ok(_) => println!("success!"),
    Err(e) => println!("sorry, got {}",e),
  }

  return;
}
```

but the code doesn't compile due to a type mismatch:

```
Xaviers-MacBook-Pro:graphite-rust xavierlange$ cargo build
   Compiling graphite-rust v0.0.1 (file:///Users/xavierlange/code/viasat/graphite-rust)
src/main.rs:8:5: 8:10 error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::fs::File`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected struct `std::fs::File`,
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:8     Ok(_) => println!("hi!"),
                  ^~~~~
src/main.rs:9:5: 9:11 error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::fs::File`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected struct `std::fs::File`,
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:9     Err(e) => println!("sorry, got {}",e),
                  ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
Could not compile `graphite-rust`.
```

The signature for `std::fs::File::create` is `fn create<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> Result<File>` so shouldn't I be expecting to "unwrap" the value using match? Why is it expecting a `File` value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at a simplified version of your code, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's very useful to create small examples when programming, as it helps you concentrate on a single problem at a time:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;

fn allocate(path: &str) -> File {
    File::create(Path::new(path))
}

fn main() {}
```

(I also took the liberty of aligning your code with the prevailing Rust style; I highly encourage you to learn it and love it for better community interaction!)

This gives the same error when [run on the Playpen](http://is.gd/KKTYFL):

```
<anon>:5:5: 5:34 error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::fs::File`,
    found `core::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::error::Error>`
(expected struct `std::fs::File`,
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<anon>:5     File::create(Path::new(path))
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The problem is because you have defined the return type of your function as a `File`, but the body of your function is returning a `Result`!

```
fn allocate(path: &str) -> File
```

You need to ensure that the type on your function and what the function does align. The simplest is to `unwrap` the result, which causes a thread panic on failure cases.

```
fn allocate(path: &str) -> File {
    File::create(Path::new(path)).unwrap()
}
```

You could also return a `Result` of your own, and then force the caller to deal with failure (my preferred choice):

```
use std::io;

fn allocate(path: &str) -> io::Result<File> {
    File::create(Path::new(path))
}
```

The other way of looking at your error is this half:

```
use std::fs::File;

fn allocate() -> File { unimplemented!() }

fn main() {
    match allocate() {
        Ok(..) => println!("OK!"),
        Err(..) => println!("Bad!"),
    }
}
```

Here, we are trying to `match` on a `File`, but `File` is not an enumeration with the variants `Ok` and `Err` - that would be `Result`! Thus, you get an error indicating such:

```
<anon>:7:9: 7:15 error: mismatched types:
 expected `std::fs::File`,
    found `core::result::Result<_, _>`
(expected struct `std::fs::File`,
    found enum `core::result::Result`) [E0308]
<anon>:7         Ok(..) => println!("OK!"),
                 ^~~~~~
```

Comment: Ah! This makes sense but now I'm wondering if the compiler should have emitted an error for my allocate function? If it had pointed me to the signature/implementation mismatch in my allocate function I probably would have figured this out earlier.